# Linux error: sh: qsub: command not found

Tags: python, linux, runtime-error

I am running `shellfish.py` in my local machine. Can someone please explain me why I am getting this error: `sh: qsub: command not found`

Comment: install `qsub` on local machine.

Comment: @furas Just to make sure do I need 'torque-server torque-scheduler'? Not sure which package I need fot qsub?

Comment: How did you try to run `shellfish.py`?

Comment: @thatotherguy `./shellfish.py --pca --numpcs 10 --maxprocs 8 --file /mypath/data50 --out outfl --sge`

Comment: @MAPK I don't know - I only checked source code and found line 1036 with `which qsub` - this line is checking whether you have `qsub` installed.

https://github.com/dandavison/shellfish/blob/master/shellfish.py#L1036

Comment: @MAPK Don't use `--sge` if you are not running on Sun Grid Engine

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks! that did the trick. sge was the culprit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified `--sge` which is used to schedule jobs on Sun Grid Engine.

Since you want to run on your local machine instead of SGE, you should remove this flag.